# "permalink to this query" on data.stackexchange.com seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The "permalink to this query" on data.stackexchange.com seems to be broken.

For example if you visit the Top 50 Most Prolific Editors from the [query list page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and then click on the permalink you see the picture of Codd.

It seems to be the way the links are generated

This works fine (from the query list page)

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/303/top-50-most-prolific-editors

This not so much (from the permalink to this query)*

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/303/Top+50+Most+Prolific+Editors

<sub>*Unless of course you wanted to a picture of Codd</sub>

[image]

Comment: what's funny is the stuff after the id shouldn't matter at all, methinks the routing setup is goofed on data.se

Comment: Edgar F. Codd, indeed.  Every StackExchange site page-not-found and site-unavailable is an Easter Egg.

Comment: Looks like there are some encoding issues as well -- the title for that query is exposing <br>'s.

Comment: It appears that this isn't fully limited to the "permalink to this query" link, [but also affects a manner of other links as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95053/data-explorer-site-switch-breaks-by-changing-polarity).

Comment: @Grace. Actually its even worse. A number of links result in "Server Error in '/' Application." For example the query "How many upvotes do I have towards tag-specialist badges?" on the [featured page](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured)

Comment: At least some of this is due to mistakes in upgrading the project to razor views.  I suppose I'll have to blame myself.  Will get it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah...sorry about that.

I pushed out a fix, should be good to go now.