# Data Explorer site-switch breaks by changing polarity

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“permalink to this query” on data.stackexchange.com seems to be broken.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/permalink-to-this-query-on-data-stackexchange-com-seems-to-be-broken)

Queries in the Data Explorer are followed by a slug that replaces spaces with dashes. For example, `http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/208/keystrokes-per-rep-point`. However, when you try and switch sites, the URL replaces all of those minus signs with plus signs, a la `http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/208/Keystrokes+per+rep+point`. This causes an error when you try to change site for the same query, since apparently it doesn't like positive attitude.

Comment: @ChrisF It was *technically* correct! I'm changing where my sights are focused! ♪

Comment: Something is wack with the whole system. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/permalink-to-this-query-on-data-stackexchange-com-seems-to-be-broken

Comment: @Jon Aye, should probably expand that report to be "All links on Data Explorer". Voted.

Comment: ...+1 for the question title, I totally didn't get that before. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave the server a talking to.  I had to stomp my foot a few times, but it will now handle positive attitudes.

(I also fixed the encoding issue that was changing the polarity in the first place.)

Comment: Almost there -- see the big query title under the headers: http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/1481/most-popular-tags-for-a-users-first-posts

Comment: ...annnd the profile page: http://data.stackexchange.com/users/1674